# Slick for Scala compiler version 2.9.1

Tags: scala, maven, slick

I am trying to install slick in to my build.sbt this way:

```
   name := "project"

   version := "1.0"

   scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

   libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "1.0.1"
```

and I am getting a an error when I am running my sbt

```
> run
[info] Updating {file:/home/chris/project/}project...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.9.1;1.0.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.9.1;1.0.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/chris/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.9.1/1.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/slick/slick_2.9.1/1.0.1/slick_2.9.1-1.0.1.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.9.1;1.0.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.9.1;1.0.1: not found
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed Sep 12, 2013 5:09:25 PM
```

The url in the error is not available, my question is where can I get the code for this specific version if I cannot get it from that public url, and once I have the code where do I install it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slick is unfortunately not available for Scala 2.9, as it takes advantage of features available in Scala 2.10+.

You can however utilize [ScalaQuery](http://scalaquery.org/), which is the spiritual predecessor to Slick and shares much of its design and features. Stefan Zeiger, who wrote ScalaQuery, now works for us at Typesafe on Slick.